# Background visual artifact in \includegraphics (probably linked to image resize)

Tags: graphics

I have the following (resized) image in my code:

```
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./images/6-1.jpg}
```

The next image in this post is the print screen of the visual result of this line of code. Below it you can see the exact same image, but with high contrast + low brightness in order to highlight the presence of the artifact.

[image]

This here is the original image. I have checked the background color, it is indeed pur white (`#ffffff`):

[image]

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this post, I found a fix outside LaTeX: make the white become transparent and save it as png (which allows to keep the transparent part of the image, unlike jpg). If you are using PS this is achieved using `magic wand => select background => Del`. Anyway, I still hope that someone finds a solution to this LaTeX issue, it can be a big deal if you are trying to print a book and you want it to look good (which is what I am currently working in).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: your image is rendered without artifacts on my system, using the graphicx package and pdflatex from TeX Live 2013, on various viewers (I tried evince, acroread, xpdf), both in scaled and original size, also when altering brightness and contrast (in GIMP). What is your setup (OS, LaTeX version, packages, pdf viewer) and MWE?

Comment: @Marijn I am using the package MiKTeX 2.9. From its release notes: `BibTeX 0.99d, Dvipng 1.14, Dvips 5.99, MakeIndex 1.15, pdfTeX 1.40.11, TeXworks 0.4, XeTeX 0.9997.4`. About the problem, I feel compelled to underline that the artifact is not easy to see (at least in my computer) with a simple visual inspection, but once you adjust high contrast + low brightness it becomes evident (as shown in the original post). I presume you have already taken this into account, but I thought it was worth stressing that part. Although if newer versions work already, that's good enough for me.

Comment: Thanks, I had similar problem, solution is to fix background color to `white` which matches an object in my drawing.  It seems that using transparent background with a white object leaves artifact edges surrounding it.